# Encountered the symbol v_PrepareStmt in Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace procedure Audit_procedure
as
v_Chunk number(10) := 20000; 
v_PrepareStmt nvarchar(20000);
v_InsertStmt nvarchar(20000);
v_SelectStmt nvarchar(20000);
v_DeleteStmt nvarchar(20000);
v_UpdateStmt nvarchar(20000);
v_TempStmt nvarchar(20000);
v_Columns NVARCHAR(20000);
```

-- Dynamic objects of query

```
v_Audit_DB nvarchar2(20):= 'Bell_Audit';
v_SO_DB nvarchar2(20) :='Bell_kat_4';
v_InsertTbl nvarchar2(20):='W6Audit_History';
v_SelectTbl nvarchar2(20):='W6Audit';
begin
```

-- Create temp w6key table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempW6key') IS NOT NULL THEN 
execute immediate ' drop TABLE #TempW6key';
END IF;
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE #TempW6key (W6key number(10) NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT W6PK PRIMARY KEY(
W6Key 
); ON [PRIMARY]
END;'
```

-- Preparing columns for insert select statements

```
v_PrepareStmt :=N'
SELECT @Columns=@Columns+''[''+SO.COLUMN_NAME+''],''
FROM '||v_SO_DB||'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS SO
INNER JOIN
'||v_Audit_DB||'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AUDIT
ON SO.COLUMN_NAME=AUDIT.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE SO.TABLE_NAME = N'''||v_SelectTbl||'''
AND AUDIT.TABLE_NAME = N'''||v_InsertTbl||'''';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  SP_EXECUTESQL; v_PrepareStmt,
N'@Columns NVARCHAR(MAX)='''' OUTPUT', v_Columns=v_Columns OUTPUT     
v_Columns :=SUBSTR(v_Columns, 1, LENGTH(RTRIM(v_Columns)) - 1); 


END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 

PRINT 'ERROR ON COLUMNS BUILD'
RAISERROR ( '', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
RETURN;

END CATCH
```

-- Preparing all statements

```
v_TempStmt:=            'INSERT INTO #TempW6key (W6Key)
SELECT W6Key FROM ['||v_SO_DB||'].[dbo].['||v_SelectTbl||'] WITH(NOLOCK)';
```

-- Create temp w6keys table to move from Audit into Audit_History

```
v_InsertStmt:='INSERT INTO ['||v_Audit_DB||'].[dbo].['||v_InsertTbl||'] 
('||v_Columns||')'; -- Insert into Audit History statment part 1

v_SelectStmt:='SELECT '||v_Columns||' FROM ['||v_SO_DB||'].[dbo].['||v_SelectTbl||']
WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE W6Key IN (SELECT W6Key FROM #TempW6key WITH(NOLOCK))';
```

-- Insert into Audit History statment part 2

```
v_DeleteStmt:='DELETE FROM ['||v_SO_DB||'].[dbo].['||v_SelectTbl||'] 
WHERE W6Key IN (SELECT W6Key FROM #TempW6key WITH(NOLOCK))'; -- Delete archived records older than 1 day from Audit
```

-- Executing all statements

```
/* BEGIN TRANSACTION */; toAuditHistory

BEGIN TRY
```

-- Statements Execution Start

```
SET ROWCOUNT v_Chunk           

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  v_TempStmt;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  v_InsertStmt||v_SelectStmt;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  v_DeleteStmt;
```

-- Statements Execution End

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION; toAuditHistory;

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
RAISERROR ( 'Iteration Failed, Rolling back', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION toAuditHistory;
RETURN;              
END CATCH.
end;
```

Comment: This appears to be a very odd combination of SQL Server T-SQL syntax and Oracle PL/SQL syntax.  It is tagged for Oracle.  Are you actually using Oracle?  Or SQL Server?  What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: What actually is the question ? This snippet: `SELECT @Columns=@Columns+` will not work on Oracle, this is a syntax coming from SQL-Server. I vote to close your question as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I converted the SQL procedure using online tool to oracle.. what shall i use instead of this ? SELECT @Columns=@Columns+

Comment: I changed the code to below and it worked

v_PrepareStmt :=
"SELECT &&Columns= FROM dual&&Columns+''''+SO.COLUMN_NAME+'',''
FROM '||v_SO_DB||'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS SO
INNER JOIN
'||v_Audit_DB||'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AUDIT
ON SO.COLUMN_NAME=AUDIT.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE SO.TABLE_NAME = N'''||v_SelectTbl||'''
AND AUDIT.TABLE_NAME  = N'''||v_InsertTbl||''''';"